# Liferay - display only top menu pages in navigation portlet

Tags: navigation, liferay, portlet

I need to use **Navigation portlet (71)** to display only **top menu pages (level 0)**.

It is not possible to configure this portlet in such way through his **Configuration**. So, the question is, what is the best approach to solve this problem:

- Create new portlet (navigation-like)
- Hook navigation portlet
- Any other ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation portlet is using Liferays tag - `liferay-ui:navigation`. You can create a small jsp-hook to override `/html/taglib/ui/navigation/page.jsp`. In this jsp you can make your modifications in how to display the items.

Also check the `nestedChildren` attribute in `liferay-ui:navigation`. I don't remember what exactly it does, but could be something helpful for your case.